# Short five lemma and a counterexample: commutative diagram

Tags: abstract-algebra, solution-verification, modules, group-isomorphism, diagram-chasing

Let's say we have the following diagram
$$\require{AMScd}\begin{CD}
 0 @>>> A @>>> B @>>> C @>>> 0\\
{} @V{\alpha}VV @V{\beta}VV @V{\gamma}VV {} \\
0 @>>> A' @>>> B' @>>> C' @>>> 0
\end{CD}$$
where the top and bottom rows are short exact, so if $f: A \rightarrow B$ and $f': A' \rightarrow B'$ are injectives and $g:B \rightarrow C$, $g': B' \rightarrow C'$ surjectives, then $\text{Im}(f)= \text{ker}(g)$ and $\text{Im}(f')= \text{ker}(g')$. The short five lemma says that if the diagram is commutative and $\alpha$ and $\gamma$ are modules isomorphisms, then $\beta$ is an isomorphism.

Is it true that if $A \simeq A'$ and $C \simeq C'$ then there's an isomorphism $\beta :B \rightarrow B'$ such that the diagram is commutative? The hint is: let $A = A' = \mathbb{Z}_2$, $C = C' = \mathbb{Z}_2 \oplus \mathbb{Z}_2$ and $B = B' = \mathbb{Z}_4 \oplus \mathbb{Z}_2$ with $\alpha = \gamma = id$ and
$$g(a \text{ mod }4, b\text{ mod }2) = (a\text{ mod }2,b\text{ mod }2) \\
g'(a\text{ mod }4, b\text{ mod }2) = (b\text{ mod }2,a\text{ mod }2).$$
Find two injective morphisms $f,f': \mathbb{Z}_2 \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_4 \oplus \mathbb{Z}_2$ such that the top and bottom row are exact but there's no isomorphism $\beta: \mathbb{Z}_4 \oplus \mathbb{Z}_2 \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_4 \oplus \mathbb{Z}_2$ such that the diagram is commutative.

So for my proof, I started by finding

$$\text{ker}(g) = \text{ker}(g') = \left\{(0,0), (2,0) \right\},$$
here I mean $(0,0) = ([0],[0])$ the corresponding classes. So, the functions $f,f'$ that satisfies the conditions are $f=f'$ such that $f(0) = (0,0), f(1) = (2,0)$ (because $\text{Im}(f)=\text{ker}(g)$). Now, suppose that there is an isomorphism $\beta: \mathbb{Z}_4 \oplus \mathbb{Z}_2 \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_4 \oplus \mathbb{Z}_2$ such that the diagram is commutative. Then $\beta \circ f = f' \circ \alpha$ i.e., $\beta \circ f = f$. So I should prove that $g=g' \circ \beta$ doesn't hold. Now my teacher said that since there're only $4$ possible $\beta$ isomorphisms, this can be made by hand (it is easy if $\beta = id$ because $g \neq g'$). My question is, is there a way to complete the proof without checking the condition  for all possible isomorphisms $\beta$? Thanks

Comment: Though Hagen von Eitzen's answer is good, I think it's worth pointing out that your counterexample disproves a weaker statement, since you show that the reverse theorem fails even if we assume $B \simeq B'$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $(a,b)=\beta^{-1}(1,0)$. Then $(a,b)$ has order $4$ in $B$, so $a$ is odd. Therefore
$$
g(a,b) = (1,b) \ne (0,1) = g'\circ\beta(a,b).
$$

Comment: "Then $(a,b)$ has order $4$ in $B$, so $a$ is odd" can you plase add details on that? I think I didn't understand

Comment: $\beta$ is an isomorphism, so the order of $(a,b)$ is the same as the order of $(1,0)$, which is $4$. The elements in $B$ with order $4$ are $(1, 0), (1,1), (3,0)$ and $(3,1)$.

Answer (score 8):

Two much work.

---

Simply observe that there are pairs of short exact sequences such as
$$ 0\to \Bbb Z_2\to\Bbb Z_4\to \Bbb Z_2\to 0$$
and
$$ 0\to \Bbb Z_2\to\Bbb Z_2\oplus \Bbb Z_2\to \Bbb Z_2\to 0$$
where the middle terms are not isomorphic.

Comment: Two or three much work? Sorry for this silly comment ;-)